# How can I clone a Wicket Component, retaining it's configuration, but changing it's ID

Tags: java, components, wicket

I've recently started working with Apache Wicket in a collaborative java project that has been using Wicket for a while. I currently have the following problem:

I have a method where I receive a list of components and, due to some project requirements, I can't change their source generator.

```
private List<Component> createNewComponents(List<Component> components) {
// create new list of components with different IDs and some other logic
}
```

I need to clone each of the components I received to create a new set of components, but with different IDs. I know I can't change a component's ID and that's why I'm trying to clone or copy the component parameters in some way, although I have not yet been successful.

Does anyone know if this is possible? And if so, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the model and the behaviors of the components through:

[`getModel()`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#getDefaultModel%28%29)

[`getBehaviors()`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#getBehaviors%28%29)

The class of the Component you can obtain by [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) so you could try to create new components with different id's with this things. But imho this is very bad design.

Comment: Hi. I decided to create a clonable panel and set any panels that I needed to receive as an extension of this one. The panel.clone() method used visitChildren() and a custom IVisitor, along with the cited methods for each panel component (getModel and getBehaviors). I was able to come up with a a working method, but in the end we had to completely change the application logic. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official, supported way to do that. You can set it using reflection, but if you can't figure out how to do it, just don't :)

You can, however, use a `RepeatingView` to add unknown components:

```
add(new RepeatingView("unknownComponents")
    .add(new Label("foo", "Foo"))
    .add(new Label("bar", "Bar")));

<div wicket:id="unknownComponents"></div>
```

generates

```
<div id="foo1">Foo</div><div id="bar2">Bar</div>
```

It works as long as the components you add to the `RepeatingView` have different IDs, and all of them use the same HTML tag. But I think you may use multiple `RepeatingViews` to work around that limitations, though.